# How to get amazon product advertising soap api working with cxf-client and grails 2.3?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I would like to use the amazon product advertising soap api within my grails application.
I already created the configuration for cxf-client plugin in my Config.groovy and generated the java classes from the wsdl:

```
// client configuration
cxf {
    client {

        // amazon product advertising api client
        amazonClient {
            wsdl = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl"

            clientInterface = com.amazon.webservices.awsecommerceservice._2011_08_01.AWSECommerceServicePortType
            serviceEndpointAddress = "https://soap.amazon.de/onca/soap?Service=AWSECommerceService"
        }
    }
}
```

Now i need to configure the security authentication with the Amazon API. There are two possibilities to do this described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/SOAP_SOAPAuth.html

Which one would you choose and how can i configure cxf-client correctly to get it working?